# LESS docs on guarded mixins -- why will this rule not match any mixins?

Tags: css, less, boolean-logic

Having primarily used SASS when writing CSS, I am now preparing to try out LESS as well. Having a read through the docs, I'm confused with the following in the context of [guarded mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions):

> Additionally, the keyword true is the only truthy value, making these
>   two mixins equivalent:
>
> ```
> .truth (@a) when (@a) { ... }
> .truth (@a) when (@a = true) { ... }
> ```
>
> Any value other than the keyword true is falsy:
>
> ```
> .class {   
>   .truth(40); // Will not match any of the above definitions.
> }
> ```

Why will `truth(40)` not match the first mixin? Doesn't `when (@a)` simply state that only match the mixin if a value (*any* value) is given to `@a`, essentially, if `@a` exists? And since `40` is a value that exists, why would it not find a match in the given mixins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For Conciseness...

...I think. It appears to be assumed by the programmers of LESS that if you do not want a *guard* on the mixin, then you of course put no `when` statement at all:

```
.truth(@a) { ... }
```

This mixin is called regardless of the value of `@a`, but does *require* a value for `@a`, and so is checking by default for "existence" of a value. So by the *adding* of a `when` guard, they have assumed one does indeed intend a *further guard* (and not just to allow any value), and so...

```
.truth (@a) when (@a) { ... }
```

...makes for a *shorthand* way (LESS is about trying to speed coding) of writing the guard statement...

```
.truth (@a) when (@a = true) { ... }
```

This makes for faster coding of a mere true/false switch for a guard, and probably seemed to be good sense over what would otherwise be a redundant statement if it instead evaluated the `when (@a)` as `true` for any value.

It is, admittedly, a bit less intuitive (no pun intended) from a typical programming viewpoint where it would seem that if `@a` *exists* (as in, anything other than `false`, `null`, or `0`) then the phrase `when (@a)` would evaluate to `true`.  But instead of checking for "existence" of a value, they have made that check an *explicit* check for a *passed* value of `true` (their only "truthy value" as far as guards are concerned).

I don't have any documentation to back up my statements here, other than the statements on lesscss.org about how they *have* coded it, which state nothing about *why* they coded it to work that way (that part is my speculation at present, unless I can track down documentation of discussion about it).

Comment: Thank you for the discussion, it does more or less make sense. To my understanding, the value 40 is then not acceptable in either of these mixins because it is not an explicit boolean expression? Meaning, I should pass to `.truth` either the keyword `true`, or an expression that evaluates to true, such as `2 = 2`. But because 40 is just kind of ... there, it doesn't evaluate to true. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I understand it to work. Being "there" is expected simply by `.truth(@a)` (it will give a compile error if no value is passed to `@a`, so that becomes your existence check). [This recent feature request is somewhat related to this](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1400).

Comment: +1 Great answer! I just wanted to add that instead of having Less throw an error you could simply have `.true(@a){ ... }` do something when `@a` is set and `.truth(){ ... }` do something else when no value is passed. Or check also for boolean: `.truth (@a) when not (@a=false) { is: true; }` if value is set and not `false`, `.truth (@a) when (@a=false) { is: false; }` if value is set to `false`, and `.truth () { is: NULL; }` when no value is set.