# How do I execute a LESS guard when a boolean is not true?

Tags: css, less, guard, not-operator

embeddable is a custom LESS PHP function that returns a boolean.

I can do something with a LESS (lessphp) guard when a boolean function returns true:

```
.my-mixin(@url) when(embeddable(@url)) {
    background-color: #abc;
}

.smallClass {
    .my-mixin('small.png');
}
```

It yields:

```
.smallClass {
    background-color: #abc;
}
```

as expected.

How do I do it when that is *not* true (not operator). The obvious:

```
.my-mixin(@url) when(embeddable(@url)) {
        background-color: #abc;
}

.my-mixin(@url) when(not(embeddable(@url))) {
        background-color: #389;
}

.bigClass {
        .my-mixin('big.png');
}
```

is silently dropped, along with the block using it.  Note, I kept the true version of the guard, so in case the predicate was wrong, the true version should be used. I then tried:

```
.my-mixin(@url) when(!embeddable(@url)) {
    background-color: #389;
}
```

in place of the not version.

The mixin is just preserved into the CSS (rather than compiled), and the bigClass block that tries to use it is still silently dropped.

Same with:

```
.my-mixin(@url) when(embeddable(@url) != true) {
        background-color: #389;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite about lessphp (can't test with it right now) but in less.js `when(not(embeddable(@url)))` is a wrong syntax resulting in a error. Try `when not(embeddable(@url))` instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Proper LESS Syntax

Note the change below in your code of the `not` version:

```
.my-mixin(@url) when (embeddable(@url)) {
        background-color: #abc;
}

.my-mixin(@url) when not (embeddable(@url)) {
        background-color: #389;
}

.bigClass {
        .my-mixin('big.png');
}
```

### Caution

Per the [lesscss.org site](http://www.lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions), "the keyword `true` is the only truthy value," which can be somewhat confusing. What this means in your example is that the PHP function needs to return the value `true` to get a hit on the `true` mixin, and anything else will be false. If you were to pass `1` (often considered true in programming languages) or even if you were to pass from your example `'big.png'` it would not match to true, so graphically (as if the value has been passed), these are the results of various passed combinations:

```
.my-mixin('big.png') when (true) <-- evaluates to TRUE
.my-mixin('big.png') when (1) <-- evaluates to FALSE
.my-mixin('big.png') when ('big.png') <-- evaluates to FALSE (most confusing)
.my-mixin('big.png') when ('true') <-- evaluates to FALSE (as it is a string)
```

For some further discussion on this "truthy" aspect of LESS, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991112/less-docs-on-guarded-mixins-why-will-this-rule-not-match-any-mixins/17993736#17993736).